# Quick Smoke Causing Grainy Renders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation, noise-reduction

I was messing around a bit with Blender 2.79, and what i found was when i was doing smoke simulations, the renders turned out really grainy with a lot of noise (kind of like scattered pixels around the smoke) in the simulation its self. I never really came across this problem till now, maybe there's something that I'm missing? I attached an image below, I hope you know what I'm talking about. :)

[image: Annoying noise]
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so i found the problem i had if anyone interested... it had to do with my lighting. i guess for smoke simulations you cant use planes with a emmision node property. i had to use actual lamps or sun lights to avoid noise, but i still cant get it around my head how that works.

Thanks.

Comment: Lamps are generally much more efficient that using emission meshes, resulting in the need for much fewer samples to render the noise out of the scene. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89665/29586 for a comparison - the same would be true for rendering a volume (smoke).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! you're right, once I dug a bit deeper emission meshes are really only at their full potential on scene lighting. Thanks!